# how to use GNU Time with pipeline

Tags: bash, time, gnu, pipeline

I want to measure the running time of some SQL query in postgresql. Using BASH built-in time, I could do the following:

```
$ time (echo "SELECT * FROM sometable" | psql)
```

I like GNU time, which provides more formats. However I don't know how to do it with pipe line. For simplicity, I use `ls | wc` in the following examples:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%es" (ls | wc)                                                      
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

$ /usr/bin/time -f "%es" "ls | wc"                                                  
/usr/bin/time: cannot run ls | wc: No such file or directory
```

If I do not group the pipe in any way, it does not complains:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%es" ls | wc       
0.00s
```

But apparently, this only measure the first part of the pipe, as showing in the next example

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%es" ls | sleep 20                                                  
0.00s
```

So the question is what is the correct syntax for GNU Time with pipe line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Call the shell from `time`:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%es" bash -c "ls | wc"
```

Of course, this will include the shell start-up time as well; it shouldn't be too much, but if you're on a system that has a lightweight shell like `dash` (and it's sufficient to do what you need), then you could use that to minimize the start-up time overhead:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%es" dash -c "ls | wc"
```

Another option would be to just time the command you are actually interested in, which is the `psql` command. `time` will pass its standard input to the program being executed, so you can run it on just one component of the pipeline:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM sometable" | /usr/bin/time -f "%es" psql
```

Comment: The last solution is perfect for my problem. The others are more flexible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create a script that calls your pipeline. Then

```
/usr/bin/time -f '%es' script.sh
```